# PHP/APC Canonicalize not working as expected

Tags: php, debian, mediawiki, alternative-php-cache

Basic Info:

```
APC Version     3.1.13
PHP Version     5.4.7-1~dotdeb.0
APC Host        pcgamingwiki.com (li263-94) (173.255.253.94)
Server Software nginx/1.2.4
```

In my config, I have apc.stat = 0 and apc.Canonicalize = 1

apc.php: http://pcgamingwiki.com/apc.php

I've got several mediawiki installs that have a lot of common files, since I'm limited on ram I was looking for ways to use APC to its fullest, I discovered that in theory if I symlinked common files (Like /var/www/includes/ to /var/www2/includes) it should realpath to the same path /var/www/includes but apc.php is showing differntly then the expected output (Have a ton more hits on /var/www/includes/*.php and not show any /var/www2/includes/*.php)

Here is a screenshot of what apc.php is reporting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ0Mz.png

as you can see that is not the expected output, am I just doing it wrong? or is it a bug?

Comment: Looks like you're using MediaWiki. You should consider [using a single MediaWiki installation to serve all your wikis](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family).

Comment: due to the sheer amount of changes we do, about 45% of the installs cannot be shared (Trust me I tried)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be a apc.php bug, the number of files in the cache that apc is reporting is about what it should be, this graph should help

http://pcgamingwiki.com/munin/localdomain/localhost.localdomain/php_apc_files.html

as you can see, there is a big spike (Thats me upping the ram it can use) then it starts to level out into the lower area, so you can see that it wanted to cache about 5k files before, now with proper symlinking its caching about 1.5k files

Comment: Might be a PHP bug - does realpath() dereference the symbolic links?

Comment: its libc's (I checked the source of APC) version of realpath(), I should test that and take a look